# Selenium Standalone Server won't launch Firefox except in interactive mode (Ubuntu, PHP, Selenium and php-webdriver-bindings-0.9.0)

Tags: ubuntu, selenium

I imagine this is a case of my not knowing quite the right combination of switches for starting up the Selenium Standalone server but here goes...

I have an Ubuntu desktop box that I want to run test via Selenium on.  So I've installed the latest Selenium Standalone server (selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar).  I can start up an interactive session of the server and get Firefox to run following the example [here](http://dionysus.uraganov.net/software/how-to-install-selenium-server-with-firefox-on-ubuntu-11-10/) but modified for my version of Selenium and my firefox path which is /usr/bin/firefox.

When I start up the server in a non-interactive mode something like this:

```
java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -port 4444 > /var/log/selenium/selenium-output.log 2> /var/log/selenium/selenium-error.log & echo $! > /tmp/selenium.pid
```

Then I get all the right feedback to say that the server is running.  However, when I attempt to run example.php from php-webdriver-bindings-0.9.0 (modified to remove the reference to "internet explorer") then it fails because Firefox is never launched.  Absolutely nothing is returned from example.php to my browser but I can see the server taking the commands (despite having added ini_set("display_errors",1); and error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of the file).  Also the error and output logs show no errors just simple status messages from the server startup.

Since PHP is simply passing commands to the server it seems to me that the server would have the same user whether in interactive mode or not and therefore there should be no permissions issues.

Ultimately I think I'm going to want to set up a grid for large scale operations but for now I'd really like to get just this one server working correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this works for me: http://dionysus.uraganov.net/software/how-to-install-selenium-server-with-firefox-on-ubuntu-11-10/

update:

OK. The link above was my first attempt to setup a ci-environment. now i have this startup commands and this works fine!

**ci server**

```
Xvfb -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ :22 -screen 0 1024x768x16 2>&1 &  
export DISPLAY=:22  
java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -multiWindow -browserSessionReuse -timeout 30000 -forcedBrowserModeRestOfLine "*firefox /usr/lib/firefox-9.0.1/firefox" 2>&1 &
```

**any worker**

```
java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar -role webdriver -hub http://[server-ip]:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser browserName=firefox,platform=LINUX,maxInstances=5
```

**next steps**
more browsers, startup scripts for selenium and xvfb. for selenium there are two resources:
https://github.com/feniix/selenium-grid-startup
http://www.danstraw.com/installing-selenium-server-2-as-a-service-on-ubuntu/2010/09/23/

Comment: Yeah, I believe that's the example I mentioned in the original question.  One, it doesn't set up a hub.  And two I don't want to manually enter the command each time so I've put it into a script at /etc/init.d/selenium.  As mentioned above, when in interactive mode I can start up a Firefox browser (when I alter the path to be correct for my machine).  But this needs to start on bootup by itself with the proper path to Firefox (and ultimately Chrome as well but that can wait).

Answer (score 0):

Update your command to:

```
java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role hub
```

Then you need to launch another instance for the webdriver role. Something like:

```
java -jar /usr/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser browserName=firefox,platform=LINUX,maxInstances=5
```

Now you should be able to visit `http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/console` and see the available Remote Proxy. Now when you run your test, it should work.

Comment: I have added these lines to the /etc/init.d/selenium file and the grid does appear to be working.  http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/console only shows Grid Hub 2.21.0 (Heading) and view config (link) but it isn't giving the 403 error it was before I rebooted the machine.  However, when I run example.php with localhost or 192.168.1.70 (its LAN IP) and with ports 4444 or 5555 they all return a 101 error ("Connection Reset").  Again the logs don't show anything useful.

Comment: Oooops, found a place where the guy I'd copied the script from had left 4443 in for the port and the script logic was executing his java command as well as my new one.  Rebooted the machine again.  I now get a message about the grid supporting 5 instances of firefox.  Still getting the 101 message though.

Comment: When I go to 192.168.1.70:5555/wd/hub I see a nice little screen for creating and refreshing sessions.  When I attempt to create a firefox session I get to wait a long time before it comes back telling me it can't create a new session.  I notice that the error shows that the "AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444" obviously the machine's IP is not 0.0.0.0 - could this be the problem?

Comment: Oddly the Apache server was down after the last reboot.  So I couldn't get to even basic PHP pages - that's how I found out.  Once I started up Apache the 101 errors went away.  I initially figured it had to be running to see http://192.168.1.70:5555/wd/hub/ but obviously not.  But starting Apache didn't solve the issue, I still can't start a session...